# error satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.4.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability

Tags: magento2.3, error, composer, magento-upgrade

When I tried to upgrade magento from **2.2.6** to **2.3.1**. I get the following error when try to run the below command:

> composer update

the error is as follow

```
 magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.4.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability
```

> Problem 1
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by
>   colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.4.1] but these
>   conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by
>   colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.4.1] but these
>   conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.1].

and here is my **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.1",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.2.6",
        "mrmonsters/magento2-aftership": "^1.0",
        "ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib": "^3.0",
        "amasty/stockstatus": "^1.2",
        "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.4",
        "mageplaza/module-google-recaptcha": "^1.0",
        "amasty/shopby": "^2.11",
        "amasty/base": "^1.6.5",
        "amasty/module-faq-product-questions": "~2.4.0",
        "firebear/importexportfree": "^1.0",
        "xtento/orderexport": "^2.8",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "101.2.34",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~6.0",
        "amasty/module-elastic-search": "^1.5",
        "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "1.3.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        },
        "xtento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.xtento.com"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue with the PHP version, Check this: https://github.com/magento-engcom/php-7.2-support/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using php 7.1.33. Seems like the issue is about 7.2 not being supported?